# How to calculate java CLASS hash based on field set?

Tags: java, serialization, hash

The issue:

We have serializer which serializes some object.

```
String json = serializer.serialize(myObject);
```

`MyObject` structure:

```
MyObject {
    String field1;
    Integer Field2;
    ...
}
```

I want to force everyone to change serializer if `MyObject` class definition was changed(added/removed/updated field)

So I want to put some field hash into `MySerializer` class and check it during `myObject` serialization. If value is differs from expected - throw exception or do it during application startup...

But I can't google any tool in java which help to calculate the hash. This way should platform independent and java version independent.

I think I can take all fields name and take their hashes but I am not sure that it is the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `serialVersionUID` described in docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html). Your 'serializer' could keep track of which version of `MyObject` the subsequently during runtime match this value using :

```
ObjectStreamClass.lookup(MyObject.class).getSerialVersionUID();
```

If your need the object of class `MyObject` to be verified as well, then the JSON would now have an additional field `serialVersionUID`. When the class definition is changed, the `serialVersionUID` can be changed accordingly.

```
MyObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String field1;
    Integer Field2;
    ...
}
```